# Sort object by value with lodash

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, lodash

I have an object that looks like this:

```
var unsorted = {a: 15, b: 1,c: 2, d: 4, e: 3, f: 6, g: 1}
```

And I am interested in sorted it in descending order with lodash, so the expected result should be:

```
var sortd = {b: 1, g: 1,c: 2, e: 3, d: 4, f: 6, a: 15}
```

I have tried using lodash `orderBy` but it gives an array of just the values sorted.

```
_.orderBy(tempCount, Number, ['desc'])

//Result
[1,1,2,3,4,6,15]
```

Comment: Objects don't have order. you need to use array if order is important

Comment: The answer is no! Even if you build an object with sorted properties, it is not guaranteed that they will display in the same order in the future.

Comment: come on! the order is now standard. first comes index same items in order and the the rest in insertation order.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You could build a new object with the sorted key/value pairs.

The actual standard or the order of properties:

- sort index like keys first, in order
- keep all other keys in insertation order

For a complete control over the order, take an array with the keys an take it as sorted accessor for the values.

```js
var unsorted = { a: 15, b: 1,c: 2, d: 4, e: 3, f: 6, g: 1 },
    sorted = _(unsorted)
        .toPairs()
        .orderBy([1], ['desc'])
        .fromPairs()
        .value()
        
console.log(sorted);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.11/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Descending sort with [`_.orderBy`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#orderBy) by using a the last parameter for a specific order, instead of [`_.sortBy`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#sortBy), which only allows to sort ascending.

```js
var unsorted = { a: 15, b: 1,c: 2, d: 4, e: 3, f: 6, g: 1 },
    sorted = _(unsorted)
        .toPairs()
        .orderBy(1, 'desc')
        .fromPairs()
        .value()
        
console.log(sorted);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.11/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: This is exactly what I am looking for. Thank you. 

However, how do I sort in ascending order?

Answer (score 8):

> JavaScript **does not guarantee** the order of keys in an object, this is why lodash returns you an array, because an object with ordered keys is not guaranteed. See this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5525795/does-javascript-guarantee-object-property-order).

However you can use a `Map`, which does guarantee the order of the keys.

You can do this with pure JavaScript:

```js
const unsorted = { a: 15, b: 1,c: 2, d: 4, e: 3, f: 6, g: 1 };

const sorted = new Map(Object.entries(unsorted).sort((a, b) => a[1] - b[1]));

for (const [key, val] of sorted) {
  console.log(key, val);
}
```

You have multiple ways to iterate over the content of the resulting map:

- `map.values()`: get the array of values
- `map.entries()`: get an array of `[key, value]` pairs
- `map.keys()`: get an array of keys

See [the doc about Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map).

Comment: Thanks @jo_va, but I figured out that a simple `Object.entries(unsorted).sort((a, b) => a[1] - b[1])` does the same thing without the need for the for-of loop.

Comment: Exactly, if you want the array, as shown in my answer, I just wrap this result in a Map if you want to access your values by keys, as you would with an object

Comment: Oh yeah. I understand. Thank you regardless.

Answer (score 2):

Here you have another approach (**without lodash**). Basically we create and array of type `[[key1, value1], [key2, value2],...]` using the `Object.entries(unsorted)`, then sort that array (ascending/descending) comparing the `values`, to finally construct again the object structure you have originally, first mapping pairs `[key, value]` to objects `{key: value}` and then assigning all these objects to a new one using `Object.assign()`.

```js
var unsorted = {a: 15, b: 1,c: 2, d: 4, e: 3, f: 6, g: 1};

let sortedAsc = Object.entries(unsorted)
    .sort(([k1,v1], [k2,v2]) => v1 - v2)
    .map(([x,y]) => ({[x]:y}));
    
let sortedDesc = Object.entries(unsorted)
    .sort(([k1,v1], [k2,v2]) => v2 - v1)
    .map(([x,y]) => ({[x]:y}));

let objSortedAsc = Object.assign({}, ...sortedAsc);
let objSortedDesc = Object.assign({}, ...sortedDesc);

console.log("ASC: ", objSortedAsc, "DESC: ", objSortedDesc);
```

```css
.as-console {background-color:black !important; color:lime;}
.as-console-wrapper {max-height:100% !important; top:0;}
```