# How can you get object in order when using forEach for object?

Tags: javascript

**current code**

priceHistory is object which has object.

```js
Object {
  "2020-05-17 10:43:45": Object {
    "created_at": "2020-06-17 10:43:45",
    "price": 1000,
  },
  "2020-05-17 10:43:51": Object {
    "created_at": "2020-07-17 10:43:51",
    "price": 2000,
  },
  "2020-05-17 10:43:56": Object {
    "created_at": "2020-08-17 10:43:56",
    "price": 3000,
  },
  "2020-05-17 10:44:01": Object {
    "created_at": "2020-09-17 10:44:01",
    "price": 4000,
  },
}
```

```js
Object.keys(priceHistory).forEach((history) => {
  console.log(priceHistory[history]);
});
```

**problem**

When using forEach for priceHistory, `console.log(priceHistory[history]);` outputs

```js
Object {
  "created_at": "2020-07-17 10:43:51",
  "price": 2000,
}
Object {
  "created_at": "2020-08-17 10:43:56",
  "price": 3000,
}
Object {
  "created_at": "2020-09-17 10:44:01",
  "price": 4000,
}
Object {
  "created_at": "2020-06-17 10:43:45",
  "price": 1000,
}
```

The order of object has been changed.
How can you solve this?
created_at is string and price is number.

I would appreciate it if you could give me any advices.

Comment: objects are not ordered. Use an array or a Map instead.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54520890/sort-object-by-value-with-lodash

You probably can try this one

Comment: I tested your `forEach` example. The right order is returned. How do you output it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution which avoids using `new Date ()` to perform this sorting

```js
const priceHistory = 
    { "2020-05-17 10:43:45": { "created_at": "2020-06-17 10:43:45", "price": 1000 } 
    , "2020-05-17 10:44:01": { "created_at": "2020-09-17 10:44:01", "price": 4000 } 
    , "2020-05-17 10:43:51": { "created_at": "2020-07-17 10:43:51", "price": 2000 } 
    , "2020-05-17 10:43:56": { "created_at": "2020-08-17 10:43:56", "price": 3000 } 
    } 

Object.keys(priceHistory)
  .sort((a,b)=>a.localeCompare(b))
  .forEach(history=>{
  console.log( JSON.stringify(priceHistory[history]) )
})
```

Comment: Thanks, this actually worked! what do you do by ```.sort((a,b)=>a.localeCompare(b))``` ?

Comment: this is standard JS function to compare strings (based on the idea of your input keys all having the same format)  see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare